# Using Predicate of a class to Search Generic list - Faster than looping?

Tags: .net, list, generics, predicate

Lets say we have a generic list of Class1, typically having ~100 objects for a given session.
I would like to see if the list has a particular object. ASP.NET 2.0 allows me to do this:

```
Dim objResult as Class1 = objList.Find(objSearch)
```

How does this approach rate when compared to a traditional For loop, looking at a performance perspective?

How would this vary with increase or decrease in length of the list?

Comment: Try both approaches as a micro benchmark.

Comment: The application is expected to do some near-real time processing, hence even a split hair difference would mean something when it adds up. But internal, if its still a loop then am I better off looping it myself and save the function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily see how .Net `List` implements the `Find` method using Reflector:

```
Public Function Find(ByVal match As Predicate(Of T)) As T
    If (match Is Nothing) Then
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match)
    End If
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Me._size - 1
        If match.Invoke(Me._items(i)) Then
            Return Me._items(i)
        End If
    Next i
    Return CType(Nothing, T)
End Function
```

The only difference between both implementations is that `Find` requires a call to `match` instead of having this logic inlined in the loop.

Interestingly, this simple performance:

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    persons.Add(new Person { ID = i });
}

GC.Collect();
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    persons.Find(person => person.ID == i % 100);

}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

GC.Collect();
sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        if (persons[j].ID == i % 100)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

Shows that:
Total time required to query the list using ***Find* is 05.7990078** seconds.
Total time required to query the list using ***loop* is 06.3551074** seconds.

This results seems consistent in several executions.

**Edit** - Found explanation for the advantage of `Find`:
`Find` works faster since it accesses directly the underlying array in each iteration. The loop access it through the `List` indexer, which requires for every access index verification:

```
Public Default Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As T
    Get
        If (index >= Me._size) Then
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException
        End If
        Return Me._items(index) // _items is the underlying array.
    End Get
```

Comment: Well well well.. So the Predicate does work faster.. I wonder why..
Btw.. is there a reason for those 'GC.Collect()'s ? I mean, I never use it, and as far as I know, it should be used only when we're sure that we have significant unmanaged objects in the memory. I know this is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: @Srikanth, I wonder why too, I expected the loop to work faster. I am still trying to find out why.
The calls to `GC` are here to reduce the chance that the garbage collector will work while we measure the duration. In regular code it's not required :)

Comment: @Srikanth, edited my answer with explanation to Find advantage

Comment: +1 for discovering the advantage of Find and the reason for such.

Answer (score 7):

It's exactly the same as looping - that's what it does internally.

If your list is sorted and you're looking for a particular value, you could potentially use [`BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx) instead - but if you think about it, if you don't know anything about the predicate or the order of the data, it *has* to look through each item until it finds a match. As it happens, `Find` is specified to return the *first* item in the list... so it just looks through in the obvious order.

This will be linear with the size of the list - i.e. on average, searching a list which is 10 times as big will take 10 times as long. Of course, it depends on whether and where a match is found; if the first item matches in every case, it'll finish in the same time no matter how big the list is :)

To be honest, with only 100 objects it sounds like it's very unlikely to be a bottleneck.